# why "WHERE column IS NOT NULL" does not work in my code?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code:

```
select case when grades.grade >= 8 then students.name end, 
        grades.grade,students.marks
from students, grades
where students.name is not null
order by grades.grade desc, students.name;
```

What I am going to do is hide all values that students.name = NULL such as

```
NULL 7 77 
NULL 7 34 
NULL 7 89 
NULL 7 78 
NULL 7 95 
NULL 7 88 
NULL 7 55 
NULL 7 94 
NULL 7 64
```

I would like to know how to erase the values like above?

Comment: You're not specifying an else in your case, which defaults to NULL. Since the records you show don't meet the condition grade >= 8, then your case goes to NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
select case when grades.grade >= 8 then students.name else 'ABC' end, grades.grade,students.marks
from students, grades
where students.name is not null AND grade >= 8
order by grades.grade desc, students.name;
```

This will get rid of all the null values that you received as it had grades less than 8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still do not understand why do I need "AND grade >= 8" at the end of "WHERE", we already change the name value to null aren't we?

Comment: In this case it is checking for student name column before applying this case statement. I have added name of student as 'ABC', so if the grade is less than 8 and if you remove student name is not null filter from WHERE clause then you can see all the student names as ABC for them. This is because of logical query processing order.